# how to append elements to an empty list in for loop using python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

I have a **for loop** that iterate over a list of directories and create a another list of the selected items  using append.

The problem is that when the system iterate over the list it append just the last item where it should append 3 items.

```
for folder in dirnames:
  founded_folder = re.findall("^pdf [0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-(?:[0-9]{2}?[0-9] {2}$)",folder)
  print(founded_folder)
  founded_folder.append(folder)
founded_folder
```

The result must be:

```
founded_folder["pdf 23-24-4-2018","pdf 11-12-03-2014","pdf 2-3-2-18"]
```

But i got this result :

```
founded_folder["pdf 2-3-2-18","pdf 2-3-2-18"]
```

Comment: Think carefully about the steps of your algorithm and the names that you give to things. Try describing the intended behaviour of *each line* of the code to yourself in plain English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
for folder in dirnames:
  folder1 = re.findall("^pdf [0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-(?:[0-9]{2}?[0-9] {2}$)",folder)
  print(folder1)
  for item in folder1:
     founded_folder.append(item)
founded_folder
```

Comment: i tried your answer now it display the list like this :

`[["pdf 23-24-4-2018"],[],[],["pdf 11-12-03-2014"],[],["pdf 2-3-2-18"]]`

so i have 2 problems :1) i need to be elements inside one list.
2) i need to remove the empty lists.

Comment: ok now it removes the empty lists , but still i have 3 lists inside 1 list

Comment: I revised line 5 as founded_folder.append(item[0]).

Comment: no my mistake i was appending folder1 so you nedd to return the appending of [item]

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting you founded_folder everytime:

`founded_folder = re.findall`

Instead use:

`curr_finds = re.findall`